# Groupby one column and forward replace values in multiple columns based on condition using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       cy  2018      8
1   1   bj       cy  2019      6
2   1   xd       dt  2020      7
3   2   sh       hp  2018      4
4   2   sh       hp  2019      3
5   2   sh       pd  2020      5
```

Say there are typo errors in columns `city` and `district` for rows in the `year` columns which is `2020`, so I want groupby `id` and `ffill` those columns with previous values.

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks a lot.

The desired output will like this:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       cy  2018      8
1   1   bj       cy  2019      6
2   1   bj       cy  2020      7
3   2   sh       hp  2018      4
4   2   sh       hp  2019      3
5   2   sh       hp  2020      5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works, but I'm not sure if it's the best solutions.

If you have others, welcome to share. Thanks.

```
df.loc[df['year'].isin(['2020']), ['city', 'district']] = np.nan
df[['city', 'district']] = df[['city', 'district']].fillna(df.groupby('id')[['city', 'district']].ffill())
```

Out:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       cy  2018      8
1   1   bj       cy  2019      6
2   1   bj       cy  2020      7
3   2   sh       hp  2018      4
4   2   sh       hp  2019      3
5   2   sh       hp  2020      5
```